# How can we remove dots and back slashes along with word using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

In my react hooks app while iterating the photo field, the src={photo}, it is coming as `..\public\images\photo-1654221497889.png` I would like to remove,the word `..\public\` along with dots and back slashes using regex, but this is not working for me. I am expecting to get the resultant as follows `images\photo-1654221497889.png`

```
{
searchResults.slice(0, loadRequests).map(({id, photo, name }) => (
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className="playerRow"> 
                                <label key={id}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="checkStyle1">
                                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="plyPhoto">
                                            <img src={photo.replace(/[^..\public\]/g,"")}></img>
                                        </div>
                                         <div className="plyName">
                                            <div>{name}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </label>
                            </div>  
                            
                        </div>  
                   ))}
```

Comment: `photo.replace('\.\.\\public\\','')` ?

Answer (score -1):

For this specific question, why not substring?

Specific regex: `"^[.]+\\public\\"`

General regex, keep only last two path: `"^([^\\]*\\)*(.+\\)"` and replace it with the second group: `"$2"`

If your want to learn regex, this is very concise resource: https://github.com/ziishaned/learn-regex